# Jquery Hide classes within the parent Div using (this)

Tags: jquery, dom, this, parent

Having some trouble with this one. I have a page with multiple products, shirts, pants etc. Every product comes in the same different colors:black, blue, green etc. I am trying to write some jQuery that I can use for all of the products. Basically, I have a div, with all the product images with classes for each one, for instance, the black product image is class="prodblack". I'd like to use the same classes for all products. But the way I have this setup now if I click on the blue swatch for a product ALL products show the blue one, not just the product I am currently clicking on.

Here is part of the HTML, this is just one div out of many, but they are all set up the same, same classes, same colors etc.

```
<div class="fb-col-md-4 fb-col-sm-6 col-xs-12" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <a href="#double_thick_blanket">
        <span class="product-wrap">
        <img alt="Double Thick Blanket" class="proddefault" onerror="this.onerror = null;this.src='/images/image-not-found.jpg'" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/products/pants/pants-tan.jpg">
        <img alt="Double Thick Blanket" class="prodtan" onerror="this.onerror = null;this.src='/images/image-not-found.jpg'" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/products/pants/pants-tan.jpg">
        <img alt="Double Thick Blanket" class="prodgreen" onerror="this.onerror = null;this.src='/images/image-not-found.jpg'" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/products/pants/pants-green.jpg">
        <img alt="Double Thick Blanket" class="prodblue" onerror="this.onerror = null;this.src='/images/image-not-found.jpg'" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/products/pants/pants-blue.jpg">
        <img alt="Double Thick Blanket" class="prodgray" onerror="this.onerror = null;this.src='/images/image-not-found.jpg'" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/products/pants/pants-gray.jpg">
        <img alt="Double Thick Blanket" class="prodblack" onerror="this.onerror = null;this.src='/images/image-not-found.jpg'" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/products/pants/pants-black.jpg"></span>
        <span class="productSwatches">
              <span class="squareSwatch blue"></span>
              <span class="squareSwatch gray"></span>
              <span class="squareSwatch tan"></span>
              <span class="squareSwatch green"></span>
              <span class="squareSwatch black"></span>
              <span style="clear:both"></span>
        </span>
        <section class="price-wrap">
            <h4 class="new-tree"><span itemprop="name">Double Thick Blanket</span> <em>$99.95</em></h4>
        </section></a>
</div>
```

And here is the Jquery, I started messing with the blue swatch using $(this) but can't seem to get it working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        var hideAllButBlue = ".prodgreen,.prodtan,.prodblack,.prodgray,.proddefault";
        var hideAllButBlack = ".prodgreen,.prodtan,.prodblue,.prodgray,.proddefault";
        var hideAllButGreen = ".prodblack,.prodtan,.prodblue,.prodgray,.proddefault";
        var hideAllButTan = ".prodblack,.prodgreen,.prodblue,.prodgray,.proddefault";
        var hideAllButGray = ".prodblack,.prodgreen,.prodblue,.prodtan,.proddefault";

        $(".prodgreen,.prodtan,.prodblue,.prodblack,.prodgray").hide();
        $(".proddefault").show();

        $(".blue").click(function() {
            $(this).parent('div').show('.prodblue');
            $(hideAllButBlue).hide();
        }); 

        $(".black").click(function() {
            $('.prodblack').show();
            $(hideAllButBlack).hide();
        }); 

        $(".gray").click(function() {
            $('.prodgray').show();
            $(hideAllButGray).hide();
        }); 

        $(".green").click(function() {
            $('.prodgreen').show();
            $(hideAllButGreen).hide();
        }); 

        $(".tan").click(function() {
            $('.prodtan').show();
            $(hideAllButTan).hide();
        }); 

    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I finally got it, I was using the .parent wrong I had to add the .find method to this

```
        $('.prodcontainer .blue').click(function(){
            $(this).parents('.prodcontainer').find('.prodblue').show();
            $(this).parents('.prodcontainer').find(hideAllButBlue).hide();
        });

        $(".black").click(function() {
            $(this).parents('.prodcontainer').find('.prodblack').show();
            $(this).parents('.prodcontainer').find(hideAllButBlack).hide();
        }); 

        $(".gray").click(function() {
            $(this).parents('.prodcontainer').find('.prodgray').show();
            $(this).parents('.prodcontainer').find(hideAllButGray).hide();
        }); 

        $(".green").click(function() {
            $(this).parents('.prodcontainer').find('.prodgreen').show();
            $(this).parents('.prodcontainer').find(hideAllButGreen).hide();
        }); 

        $(".tan").click(function() {
            $(this).parents('.prodcontainer').find('.prodtan').show();
            $(this).parents('.prodcontainer').find(hideAllButTan).hide();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time the other day writing an answer to this question. I had to step away and forgot about it. When I came back, I see you figured it out. That being said, [take a look at this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fk0yzo5L/2/). It reduces the number of click events down to just one.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        // All elements with .prod and .default class, display
        // I hid all .prod initially with CSS to help with FOUC    
        $('.prod.default').addClass('selected');

        // Any acceptable color
        var colors = ['tan','blue','green','black','gray'];

        $(".squareSwatch").click(function() {

            // Get the parent div
            var $product_container =  $(this).parentsUntil('div');

            // Default swatch
            var $default = $product_container.find('.prod.default');

              // Get the classes of this .squareSwatch
            var classes = $(this).attr('class');

            // Split classes on space
            classes = classes.split(' ');

            // Get the target color
            // $(classes) is an array of .squareSwatch classes
            // colors is an array of all acceptable colors
            // $(classes).not(colors) returns whichever classes are not colors
            // So $(classes).not($(classes).not(colors))
            // is first getting an array of every class that isn't a color
            // which, when matched against all classes again, returns
            // only the colors; preferably one
            // Either way, since it returns an array, [0] gets the first item
            var target_color = $(classes).not($(classes).not(colors))[0];

            var target = $product_container.find('.prod.'+target_color);

            // If target color found (not undefined)
            if(typeof(target_color) !== 'undefined'){

                 // Find and hide all elements that aren't the target color
                 $product_container.find('.prod:not(.'+target_color+')').removeClass('selected');

                 // Show the target color
                 target.addClass('selected');

            }else{ // otherwise default

                 // Hide anything that isn't default
                 $product_container.find('.prod:not(.default)').removeClass('selected')

                // Show the default
                $default.addClass('selected');

            }
        }); 

    });
```

It could be fleshed out a little bit more, but maybe it will be helpful!